# How do I sepBy ambiguous parse with Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to separate a string using a delimiter consisting of multiple characters, but the problem is that each of those characters can occur by itself in non-delimiting string. For example, I have `foo*X*bar*X*baz`, where the delimiter is `*X*`, so I want to get `[foo, bar, baz]`, but each one of those can contain `*` or `X`.

I have tried

```
sepBy (many anyChar) delimiter
```

but that just swallows the whole string, giving `"foo*X*bar*X*baz"`, if I do

```
sepBy anyChar (optional delimiter)
```

it filters out the delimiters correctly, but doesn't partition the list, returning `"foobarbaz"`. I don't know which other combination I could try.

Comment: We have 3 functions for that: `lookAhead`, `manyTill` and `between`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this,

```
tok = (:) <$> anyToken <*> manyTill anyChar (try (() <$ string sep) <|> eof)
```

The `anyToken` prevents us from looping forever at the end of input, the `try` lets us avoid being over-eager in consuming separator characters.

Full code for a test,

```
module ParsecTest where
import Control.Applicative ((<$), (<$>), (<*>))
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

sep,msg :: String
sep = "*X*"
msg = intercalate "*X*" ["foXo", "ba*Xr", "bX*az"]

tok :: Parser String
tok = (:) <$> anyToken <*> manyTill anyChar (try (() <$ string sep) <|> eof)

toks :: Parser [String]
toks = many tok

test :: Either ParseError [String]
test = runP toks () "" msg
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Had to rewrite the manyTill function as `manyTill2 p end = scan
  where
    scan  = do{ x <- end; return x }
            <|>
            do{ x <- p; xs <- scan; return (x:xs) }` 
and use lookAhead on the separator so that I could keep the delimiters of the delimiter, and only partition on the `X`.